# Chrome will not display current image / really weird

Tags: php

Just 30 mins ago I ran into a really unexpected problem (which as a matter of fact happened to me for the 1st time in my life, and in the 10 years of coding websites).

On a particular page from my admin module, few images reverted to their old state, the exact way they were few days ago. Which means I changed them yesterday, and now they all look like they were before.

It gets more weird. I logged in with Filezilla, and deleted the images. They still appear, with the way they looked 3 days ago, before I changed them.

If I go to the URL of the image it still displays the old images. If I look locally in my Windows folder they are the new version, upload them again, still the browser displays the old version.

I erased the cache in Chrome, even restarted the computer thinking there is something to do with Chrome or something, i really ran out of options. Firefox displays the same, the old images (even if i uploaded the new version of images).

I tried with CPanel FTP manager and...surprise...if i look at an image, it's the good version of images (the new one!). But all browsers fail to see the image.
Also as a keypoint, if I erase the image with ftp, the browser still sees it (SHIFT + f5, still it sees it, so it's not from cache). ?!?!

ANy pointing to the problem is really appreciate. Cheers

Comment: code or link please ? link will be better ...

Comment: it's inside an admin module that i'm developing...you can see text + pictures that are old....i'm wondering why i cannot see the updated pics ? if you ran into a similar problem you could tell, if not, you'd be as lost as I am.....simply if you go with Chrome to show the image that's being displayed, it displays it in a new window...but not the new ones....just old ones (and on the server there are new pics....even if i delete the new pics, it displays pics from 3 days ago...why?)

Comment: ctrl+f5 that is...still nuttin....

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your hosting provider has a reverse proxy that caches requests for images. One way to overcome the problem is to add something to the URL, perhaps a request parameter, that makes the proxy think that the request is not for the same image.

For example, http://www.example.com/yourimage.png?date=2012-10-25

Comment: i did Joni my answer to what i found out is above in the above comment

Comment: look for the answer above, problem has been fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the hosting provider is screwing you over, so I'd say step one is to dump them and move elsewhere...

But if Joni's suggestion doesn't work, you can build your image dynamically on the server, like:

```
<img src="imageHandler.php?image=myimage.png" />
```

Your imageHandler.php code would need to read the bytes of the image, and build the HTTP response manually and pass the image bytes back. Not sure what that would look like in PHP, but it shouldn't be more than a few lines of code.

This is a terrible solution, since it would require a ton of processing and disk access for a trivial task like pulling images, but I'd expect that it would at least work.

Comment: do you know what they told me ? i contacted them and they said they did a jpeg version of the png (one of the files) and that works, so i should do jpegs all through my website...are they nuts ? jpegs don't use transparency and i relay heavily on transparency....and the provider is excellent when it comes to bandwidth and now also storage and prices...they basically do 24 euros for 10mbps, unmetered and 100 GB space and 170 euros for 4x500 mirrored raid + 2x180 SSD for database + 30mbps internationally and 1gbps countrywide...you can imagine i cannot beat that elsewhere here.. :)

Comment: the problem was "an erroneous configuration (misconfig) of the virtual host in their linux config file, for my domain. cheers all for sharing your oppinions on this with me. so if anyone can see old pictures that there are not there or delete pictures from server and still see old pictures , it's virtual host conf file misconfig on the linux box. cheers all

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out. I haven't priced out that kind of thing before, so I don't know what kind of deal that is, but even if it is a great deal, if they are the kind of company that screws up configuring their virtual servers, and provide support that tells you to switch image formats, it may be worth a few extra bucks to find someone better.

Comment: EDIT to answer: I forgot to format the HTML, so now it's showing what I was trying to describe. Even though it's a non-issue now...

Comment: oh well, i ran into a lot of problems with them...that after few hours or days proved to be...related to my work :)) this was the only problem i had with them related to their part of work, but their deal and offer is solid that's why i'm with them, i have plenty of offers to choose from :)) i'm glad this one was sorted out :)) cheers all and waiting to get some more into coding so i can post other interesting stuff here that other might benefit from

Answer (score 0):

it's the first time i answer my own question cause it was related to external factors.

yes, problem was fixed, it was actually the guys at tech. dept. at the ISP i have the files hosted, the virtual hosts config file for my domain xxx.net was ..misconfigured.

cheers all, problem is fixed